# How to split string using batch file?

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, split, command

- How to split string using batch script?

> SET java_path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31"

above is my string, i want only "C:\Program Files" from java_path. how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may split strings by character position:

`ECHO %java_path:~1,16%`

or by splitting at specific characters:

`FOR /F "DELIMS=\ TOKENS=1,2" %i IN (%java_path%) DO ECHO %i\%j`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "java_path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31"
SET "this=%java_path:~3%"
SET "this=%this:*\=%"
CALL SET "this=%%java_path:%this%=%%"
SET "this=%this:~0,-1%"
ECHO %this%
```